# Where To Put Wine Gecko msi

Tags: wine

I've just downloaded **wine_gecko-2.47-x86.msi**. The official installation notes say it should be placed in  `/usr/share/wine/gecko` or `$prefix/share/wine/gecko/` if wine was installed elsewhere.
Although I just installed wine via "`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel`" (incl. previous steps) there is no folder wine in either `/usr/share/` nor anywhere else.

This is where the files are located:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/function_grep.pl
/usr/bin/msiexec
/usr/bin/notepad
/usr/bin/regedit
/usr/bin/regsvr32
/usr/bin/widl
/usr/bin/wine
/usr/bin/wine-preloader
/usr/bin/wine64
/usr/bin/wine64-preloader
/usr/bin/wineboot
/usr/bin/winebuild
/usr/bin/winecfg
/usr/bin/wineconsole
/usr/bin/winecpp
/usr/bin/winedbg
/usr/bin/winedump
/usr/bin/winefile
/usr/bin/wineg++
/usr/bin/winegcc
/usr/bin/winemaker
/usr/bin/winemine
/usr/bin/winepath
/usr/bin/wineserver
/usr/bin/wmc
/usr/bin/wrc
/usr/share
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/wine.desktop
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/winehq-devel
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/de.UTF-8
/usr/share/man/de.UTF-8/man1
/usr/share/man/de.UTF-8/man1/wine.1
/usr/share/man/de.UTF-8/man1/winemaker.1
/usr/share/man/de.UTF-8/man1/wineserver.1
/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8
/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8/man1
/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8/man1/wine.1
/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8/man1/winemaker.1
/usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8/man1/wineserver.1
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/msiexec.1
/usr/share/man/man1/notepad.1
/usr/share/man/man1/regedit.1
/usr/share/man/man1/regsvr32.1
/usr/share/man/man1/widl.1
/usr/share/man/man1/wine.1
/usr/share/man/man1/wineboot.1
/usr/share/man/man1/winebuild.1
/usr/share/man/man1/winecfg.1
/usr/share/man/man1/wineconsole.1
/usr/share/man/man1/winecpp.1
/usr/share/man/man1/winedbg.1
/usr/share/man/man1/winedump.1
/usr/share/man/man1/winefile.1
/usr/share/man/man1/wineg++.1
/usr/share/man/man1/winegcc.1
/usr/share/man/man1/winemaker.1
/usr/share/man/man1/winemine.1
/usr/share/man/man1/winepath.1
/usr/share/man/man1/wineserver.1
/usr/share/man/man1/wmc.1
/usr/share/man/man1/wrc.1
/usr/share/man/pl.UTF-8
/usr/share/man/pl.UTF-8/man1
/usr/share/man/pl.UTF-8/man1/wine.1
```

So where to should I cut & paste gecko?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "find" command to find wine folder:

```
find / -name wine
```

For me is:

```
/opt/wine-devel/share/wine
```

Comment: Using `locate wine` will return the same results much faster... but then again. Can you add to your answer where to put the file? I'm not sure it really belongs to `/opt/wine-devel/share/wine`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the excerpt below from https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu You don't copy and paste gecko anywhere you simply agree to it's installation when creating a new prefix.

*If you have previously used the distro packages, you will notice some differences in the WineHQ ones:*

**Files are installed to /opt/wine-devel.**

*Menu items are not created for Wine's builtin programs (winecfg, etc.), and if you are upgrading from a distro package that had added them, they will be removed. You can recreate them yourself using your menu editor.*

*Binfmt_misc registration is not added. Consult your distro's documentation for update-binfmts if you wish to do this manually.*

*WineHQ does not at present package wine-gecko or wine-mono.
 When creating a new wine prefix, you will be asked if you want to download those components. For best compatibility, it is recommended to click Yes here. If the download doesn't work for you, please follow the instructions on the Gecko and Mono wiki pages to install them manually.*